# New Blank Page(XAML) projects = Controls are not showing on the MainPage(only their borders are)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

I'm new to Visual Studio and couldn't find my answer anywhere else for hours over the internet..

I'm Using "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows" and everytime I create a new project with a blank page (XAML), the designer only shows me the frame of the page with its missing background. 
And any control I drag to it, is invisible (I can only see the square border of the control I dragged but no texture..)

This is only happening during design time. On RunTime it actually shows up..

This is happening to me since I had the first fresh install. Just to be clear, I am NOT opening an existing previous project.. I have non. This is the first time I make a project in C# and I'm surprised I didn't find anything useful so far over internet search..

Also tried installing, uninstalling, repairing and changing to different versions... 
The problem didn't show on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop, but this product doesn't seem to be fit to my needs.. (I'm trying to also learn how to develop for Windows Store and other products)

The IDE doesn't show any errors or warnings..

Help would be much appreciated!

P.S - I'm running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try Blend to open the project and render the xaml，if the problem appear too, maybe you should check out your graphics card or update driver.

Comment: Tried with blend, same problem.. about my Video Driver, what can I do? overall it seems fine and everything else graphical (Games, etc.) seem to work fine. This only happens during design time :-(

Answer (score 0):

try with this!

Check the following:

Tools -> Options
Expand Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous
Make sure that "Always open documents in full XAML view" is not checked
Or perhaps the default program for opening .xaml files has changed:

Right-click your .xaml file in Solution Explorer
Click Open With...
Select XAML UI Designer
Click Set as Default button
Click OK

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/273ddd80-3a65-4de7-b40a-8b929f0fee5a/user-control-not-showing-in-designer-or-final-application?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

If it's related to the video driver, maybe disabling hardware acceleration will help?

Or you could try Visual Studio Community Edition (http://www.visualstudio.com/, click on the Download button under "Free developer tools"

Did one of these suggestions work?

Comment: Nothing worked.... I tried updating my Video Card. everything video related seem to work fine, and this is a new computer so I truly doubt that direction.. still tried it anyway.

Comment: I suspect it might be something with the underlying .net? could that be? maybe something got corrupted somehow.. I don't know... the only version of Visual Studio that worked out for me was VIsual Studio 2012 Desktop edition, but this is not the one I wish to use. I'm kinda stuck with it..

Comment: Might be.. Are you connecting to the computer over remote desktop?

Comment: Also, you mention XAML - does it not work for any type of XAML project? (e.g. WPF, Silverlight, Store?)